# CSS - is it possible to wrap an image with a background using pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

We have some html templates that are generally coded like this :

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png" height="50" width="100"/>
    <div class="credit">credit</div>
    <div class="caption">caption</div>
</div>
```

For the sake of clarity: An `.image` div contains an `img` element, and may contain `.credit` and `.caption` divs

Here's where my problem comes in.  Our design specification has a background image applied to the `img` element -- which should be full width of the containing box.  My freelancer  coded the templates wrong, and the background was applied to the entire `.image` div -- including the metadata ( caption and credit ).  I didn't catch this until now, when we switched out background images.

I'm wondering if there is any way to use css pseudo-elements to fix this.  I tried playing around for a bit, but I couldn't accomplish anything.

While I could recode all the templates to something like the following, i'd like to avoid it:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="image-backgrounded">
        <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png" height="50" width="100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image-meta">
        <div class="credit">credit</div>
        <div class="caption">caption</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tossed a jsfiddle online to show the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/jHmR7/2/

Comment: I assume swapping the divs out for figure and figcaption elements would be too expensive development-wise and out of the question.

Comment: Use a pseudo-element to display dynamic content? Smells bad. They're not part of the DOM.

Comment: I suppose the images don't all have the same height do they? How a bout the site background does it have a plain colour?

Comment: The images are of varying height/width.  I'm trying to avoid swapping out the HTML markup.  If needed, @BoltClock is right -- I should use figure/figcaption.

Answer (score 1):

```
.image {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.image img {
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 0px 37%; // adjust padding to fit properly based on image size

}
```

**Assumption: Images will be of same width**

If not images must be resized to same width, then this trick will work fine.

```
.image img {
        background: #CCC;
        padding: 0px 37%; // adjust padding to fit properly based on image size
        width : 40%; // define fixed width for images
    }
```